# Null Pointer Exception going throu JTable Cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a program where I can enter data into a database through a JTable. I want to be able to enter up to 10 word/ definition combinations. If I want to enter less than that, the cells are there, but that should not make a difference to the program when it goes to save the information in the database.

I have the following setup:

2 columns: word and definition &
10 rows: 10 different word and definition combinations

I was able to get the code below working to go through one row. I hard coded 0 and 1 into the y coordinate to get information out of both columns. However, I want to be able to enter multiple words/definitions (i.e. enter multiple rows of data and then save them). So, I wrote the code below, but I keep getting a `null pointer exception` at the `if loop`. I have drawn the coordinates out by hand, made sure to check if the cell was empty and used the debugger to figure out where the the exception popped up. It came up when it saw the first empty row which is good because I do not want to save blank entries, but if I am checking to see if the cell is empty, I shouldn't be getting this error. It should skip it and try the next cell in line. Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Thanks

```
public void updateDB() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/brainstormer", "me", "me");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                if (!" ".equals(glossary.getValueAt(j, i).toString())) {
                    String word = glossary.getValueAt(j, i).toString();
                    String definition = glossary.getValueAt(j, i).toString();
                    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO APP.GLOSSARY VALUES('" + word + "','" + definition + "')");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should used PreparedStatement so that it cleans up the user data otherwise you're going to be open to SQL Injection.

Comment: May be `glossary.getValueAt(j, i)` is `null`.

Comment: @Braj I worked that out with the debugger, but I am checking for emptiness with phrase in the if statement. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Try this condition `if (glossary.getValueAt(j, i) != null && glossary.getValueAt(j, i).toString().trim().length() != 0) {...}`

Comment: shouldn't the condition in j loop be `j<10`

Comment: @maxx777 Depends on the number of rows. It's a good catch.

Comment: @Braj he has already specified that he has only 10 rows in the `JTable`. though i'm not much experienced with jtables, but i felt this is the way it should have been.

Comment: Lets wait to answer it by OP itself or you can confirm it. I strongly agree with you.

Comment: Yeah that was a good catch. I did only want 10 rows (0-9) My IDE screamed at me about that once I used @Braj advice to get rid of the null pointer exception. Thanks for both suggestions.

Comment: @LearnLanguages96 so the problem was due to `j<11`?

Comment: No, the problem was fixed by the example you gave. I was hitting a cell with a null value but I suppose that doing ` if glossary.getValueAt(j,i) != " " ` was not enough. I think trimming the string and checking the length really helped me along. I was just saying that @maxx777 was right about what he said in that it should be j<10.

Comment: @Braj If you want, make it the answer so I can check it off

Comment: OK I will put it as answer. Thanks to @maxx777 also.

Comment: It was very simple solution. Its very common exception in JAVA. If in future you got it just put a `null` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a null check to avoid `NullPointerException` as shown below:

```
if (glossary.getValueAt(j, i) != null 
       && glossary.getValueAt(j, i).toString().trim().length() != 0) {...}
```